# ng-options Selección de multiples atributos en un producto

Tags: angularjs, poo, vistas

Estoy armando una vista "detalle de producto". Donde muestro un producto con un atributo "talla". De cara al cliente el producto es el mismo, pero cada talla es un producto distinto(objeto distinto).

La sección donde se selecciona la talla es asi:

```
   <label for="atributo">{{productoAtributos[0].nombre_atributo}}</label>
                        <select name="atributo" ng-options="a as a.atributos for a in productoAtributos track by a.id" ng-model="selected" ng-change="getImgDetalleProducto(selected.id);getAtributosDetalleProducto(selected.id)" data-placeholder="Seleccione una opción">
                            <option value=""></option>
                        </select>
```

y los campos de la vista se actualizan cada vez que cambio de talla asi:

```
<p class="precio">{{selected.precio}}</p>
```

El problema es que no sé cómo hacer para más de un atributo, es decir "talla" y luego "color".
Cómo hago para que los campos de la vista se actualicen luego de haber seleccionado los dos atributos.

Answer (score 0):

Da la impresión que es problema de diseño de datos. 
Estas Seleccionando el producto según la talla, pero si el color también te da una producto distinto, sin ninguna relación. es complicado el diseño.

Lo normal es que el diseño de los datos de producto fuera mas o menos así.

```
producto{
   precio:10,
   tallas:{
     xl:{
       suplemento:5
     },
     s:{
       suplemento: -5
     }
   },
   colores:{
      azul:{
       suplemento: 6
     }
   }
}
```

y entonces si que puedes jugar con los datos.